# Calculated field be todays date if condition met

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SP list that has a choice column named "Status" with "Published" and "Draft" as an option. I want todays date to be in a calculated field when "Published" is in the "Status" column. If "Status" is "Draft" I want the date to be blank. I made a calculated column with the Date and Time to be returned. If I can I would like to do this operation in a date picker column.

Comment: Do it by customising list form with power apps. Calculated column will not work properly for your requirements.